# How to pass in input in a Neural Network values that in prediction I don't know

Tags: keras, neural-network

I'm using a very easy neural network (one dense layer) with different vectorized inputs (tfidf-vectorizer) concatenated.

Training set is about fruits and vegetables and other things.

Categories/labels are [ orange, apple, garlic, strawberry, etc..].

An important value that I would like to pass is the parent category of each instance, for example:

```
category: apple
parent category in input: fruits

category: garlic
parent category in input: vegetables
```

The problem comes when I have to use my NN to predict data where I don't know the parent category, so I can't pass this information as input of my NN.

An option it could be to use 2 NN:

- the first will predict the parent category of my desired category
- the second will predict the desired category, but in input I'll put also the parent category

With this option, I could predict categories without knowing a priori the parent category.

Is there any suggestion?

Comment: Sounds to me that it’s better to ignore this info on training, because you won’t have it on prediction. Using two NN can damage your model accuracy because your second NN is relying on the first network accuracy.

Comment: it's possible that 2 NN could decrease the accuracy, but at the same time i saw that trying to train and predict on greater (more generic) category (fruits, vegetables for example, instead of having all the single fruits and vegetables) the accuracy is higher. So, passing to the 2th NN the prediciton i'll hope that the precidction is correct.